# How do I use local storage/ memory to store data for my text RPG?

Tags: javascript, database

I started making a text based RPG on Codecademy, but I need to implement a save/ load system that is in javascript/html. I was thinking about doing a system, in which they type in something like save into a prompt, then it automatically saves all of the data(player stats, maps, items, etc.) but i dont really know how I would wright ANY of that code, because I have very little experience with managing databases. If anyone could help me with links, tutorials, etc. that would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Although not the recommended technology to do this,

Yes, you can use [LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) - ([on supported browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=localstorage)), to save a *stringified* version of a Javascript object which would hold the player data.

e.g

```
var playerStats = {
    username: "Paul",
    score: "22",
    levelReached: "2",
    age: "22",
    inventory : "knife,spoon,apples"
}
```

**Saving to Local storage a *stringified* version of the JS Object:**

```
localStorage.setItem("thisPlayerStats", JSON.stringify(playerStats));
```

**Fetching & *parsing back* the string into a JS Object**

```
var playerData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('thisPlayerStats'));
```

Where `thisPlayerStats` refers to the current player for which you are saving. In a sense each user saves *only* his own scores so when retrieving `thisPlayerStats`, you are retrieving the current/visiting user's scores.

---

Keep in mind that [LocalStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) is *non-persistent memory* in a sense.
Since it is owned by the user's machine it can be wiped/modified on demand

Comment: So I would use localStorage.setItem( ); but whats the difference in 'thisPlayerStats' and playerStats? And for fetching it back, would thisPlayerStats be the variable name for player stats?

Comment: @JohnathanSeelentag Check the updated answer - `thisPlayerStats` refers to the current user's score  only. No need to store or refer to usernames. Each user only keeps his *own* score

Comment: Would I be able to save data like yours, but save multiple things, like, Player stats, then inventory, then other stuff, like map, story completion?

Comment: Yes, just add more properties to the `playerStats` object - Put a comma after `levelReached` and continue adding as many as you want - I've updated the object so you can take it as an example

Comment: Wait, one more question, could I have a prompt variable that ask's and records the username, which gets inputted into the playerStats, and have something like that save?

Comment: You can Google the rest, sayonara